# ROS Answers SE migration: ROS e gazepo

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Quero executar o gazepo com o ROS , mas trava no meu computador. Alguém sabe uma configuração mínima de hardware pra executar.?
Estou usando o ubuntu 12.04 e ROS Groovy... e 8Gb de memória

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/76030/ros-e-gazepo/) by [alexprocopio](https://answers.ros.org/users/5944/alexprocopio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-09-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm assuming you're asking about gazebo.  Usually you need a modern discrete graphics card.  For more details you should ask on gazebosim.org.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2013-11-07**:
Is there any robot with which 2D navigation stack is already setup in case of Gazebo? And we can send robot to a particular location through rviz or simple_navigation_goals.

Is there any socket involved between communication of ROS and Gazebo?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-11-07**:
@Brian Smith please ask new questions these are not directly related to answering this question.